# Python 3 - How do I extract data from SQL database and process the data and append to pandas dataframe row by row?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a MySQL database, its columns are:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| artist       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title        | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| album        | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| duration     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| artistlink   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| songlink     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| albumlink    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| instrumental | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| downloaded   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| filepath     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| language     | json         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| genre        | json         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| style        | json         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| artistgender | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to extract data from it and process the data and add the data to a pandas DataFrame.

I know how to extract data from SQL database, and I have already implemented a way to pass the data to DataFrame, but it is extremely slow (about 30 seconds), whereas when I used a flat list of namedtuples the operation is tremendously faster (under 3 seconds).

Specifically, filepath is default NULL unless the file is downloaded (currently none of the songs are downloaded), and when Python gets filepath the value will be None, and I need that value become `''`.

And because MySQL doesn't have BOOLEAN type, I need to cast the received `int`s to `bool`.

And the language, genre, style fields are tags stored as JSON lists, and they are all currently NULL, when Python gets them they are strings and I need to make them `list`s using `json.loads` unless they are None, and if they are None I need to append empty lists instead.

This is my inefficient solution to the problem:

```py
import json
import mysql.connector
from pandas import *

fields = {
    "artist": str(),
    "album": str(),
    "title": str(),
    "id": int(),
    "duration": str(),
    "instrumental": bool(),
    "downloaded": bool(),
    "filepath": str(),
    "language": list(),
    "genre": list(),
    "style": list(),
    "artistgender": str(),
    "artistlink": str(),
    "albumlink": str(),
    "songlink": str(),
}

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    user="Estranger", password=PWD, host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, database="Music"
)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def proper(x):
    return x[0].upper() + x[1:]

def fetchdata():
    cursor.execute("select {} from songs".format(', '.join(list(fields))))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    dataframes = list()
    for item in data:
        entry = list(map(proper, item[0:3]))
        entry += [item[3]]
        for j in range(4, 7):
            cell = item[j]
            if isinstance(cell, int):
                entry.append(bool(cell))
            elif isinstance(cell, str):
                entry.append(cell)
        if item[7] is not None:
            entry.append(item[7])
        else:
            entry.append('')
        for j in range(8, 11):
            entry.append(json.loads(item[j])) if item[j] is not None else entry.append([])
        entry.append(item[11])
        entry += item[12:15]
        df = DataFrame(fields, index=[])
        row = Series(entry, index = df.columns)
        df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
        dataframes.append(df)
    songs = concat(dataframes, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    songs.sort_values(['artist', 'album', 'title'], inplace=True)
    return songs
```

Currently there are 4464 songs in the database and the code takes about 30 seconds to finish.

I sorted my SQL database by artist and title and I need to resort the entries by artist, album and title for QTreeWidget, and MySQL sorts data differently from Python and I prefer Python sorting.

In my testing, `df.loc` and `df = df.append()` methods are slow, `pd.concat` is fast, but I really don't know how to create dataframes with only one row and pass flat lists to dataframe instead of a dictionary, and if there is a faster way than `pd.concat`, or if operations in the for loop can be vectorized.

How can my code be improved?

---

I figured out how to create a DataFrame with a list of lists and specify column names, and it is tremendously faster, but I still don't know how to also specify the data types elegantly without the code throwing errors...

```py
def fetchdata():                                                                          
    cursor.execute("select {} from songs".format(', '.join(list(fields))))                
    data = cursor.fetchall()                                                              
    for i, item in enumerate(data):                                                       
        entry = list(map(proper, item[0:3]))                                              
        entry += [item[3]]                                                                
        for j in range(4, 7):                                                             
            cell = item[j]                                                                
            if isinstance(cell, int):                                                     
                entry.append(bool(cell))                                                  
            elif isinstance(cell, str):                                                   
                entry.append(cell)                                                        
        if item[7] is not None:                                                           
            entry.append(item[7])                                                         
        else:                                                                             
            entry.append('')                                                              
        for j in range(8, 11):                                                            
            entry.append(json.loads(item[j])) if item[j] is not None else entry.append([])
        entry.append(item[11])                                                            
        entry += item[12:15]                                                              
        data[i] = entry                                                                   
    songs = DataFrame(data, columns=list(fields), index=range(len(data)))               
    songs.sort_values(['artist', 'album', 'title'], inplace=True)                         
    return songs
```

And I still need the type conversions, they are already pretty fast, but they don't look elegant.

Comment: You will have your database stored somewhere you can use `Sqlite` ??? :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028759/how-to-open-and-convert-sqlite-database-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a list of conversion functions for each column:

```py
funcs = [
    str.capitalize,
    str.capitalize,
    str.capitalize,
    int,
    str,
    bool,
    bool,
    lambda v: v if v is not None else '',
    lambda v: json.loads(v) if v is not None else [],
    lambda v: json.loads(v) if v is not None else [],
    lambda v: json.loads(v) if v is not None else [],
    str,
    str,
    str,
    str,
]
```

Now you can apply the function that converts the value for each field

```py
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    row = [func(field) for field, func in zip(item, funcs)]
    data[i] = row
```

Comment: Your code have two typos and I believe `fields` should be a `dict` according to your code.

Comment: Sorry - I thought to use a dict initially - perhaps hoping to combine it with your fields dict - but a list was a better fit in the end.

Comment: But it still doesn't demonstrate how to properly set data types for each field, like my `field` dictionary specified.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the [DataFrame docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) it isn't possible to set different datatypes for columns: you can either force a single type or let Pandas infer.  You might be able to improve on the initial result with the  the [infer_objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) method.  Or there may be other ways - Pandas is not my specialty

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question, for generic database 'history':

```
    import pymysql
    # open database
    connection = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","123456","blue" )
    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # prepare SQL command
    sql = "SELECT * FROM history" 
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        print ("Last row uploaded",list(data[-1]))
    except:
        print ("Error: unable to fetch data")
    # disconnect from server
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can simply fetch data from the table and create a Data-frame using Pandas.

import pymysql
import pandas as pd
from pymysql import Error
conn = pymysql.connect(host="",user="",connect_timeout=10,password="",database="",port=)
if conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = f"""SELECT * FROM schema.table_name;"""
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data =pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
    conn.close()
# You can go ahead and create a csv from this Data-Frame
    csv_gen = pd.to_csv(data,index=False)
    
    
 

    enter code here
```